# React application deploy on a gitHub pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, github-pages

Let me explain my problem. I have published my website using gitHub pages and what i got in the end was a clear page only with Header component. I use a React router in this project and I think the issue was caused by my path in browser. I attached code for better understanding.

APP Component

```
import './App.css';
import FirstPageWrapper from './components/FirstPage/PageWrapper/PageWrapper';
import {Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './components/FirstPage/Header/Header';
import PageWrapper from './components/Second page/CollectionPage/PageWrapper/PageWrapper';
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Header/>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<FirstPageWrapper/>}/>
      <Route path='/collection' element={<PageWrapper />}/>
      <Route path='/activation' element={<h1>Activation page</h1>}/>
    </Routes>
    </>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

[pay attention to the URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPDZG.png)

As you can see only Header component is outside of the router. I`ve got planty of websites and i cant just enter` https://vladaes.github.io/`URL instead of`https://vladaes.github.io/moviewebsite/`. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: App seems to render and navigate just fine if you start from `"https://vladaes.github.io/#"`. What is the issue, the URL you are trying to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see there are two thigs you should resolve for this to work.

1. You need to wrap all Router components in a [Router context provider](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/router). In your case, since you are hosting your page in a hosting service you don't fully manage, you might need to use the [Hash Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/hash-router) provider.
2. Set the `basename` of your app to `/moviewebsite`. This is a property of the Router provider. All routes will be relative to this one.

The code would end like this:

```
import './App.css';
import FirstPageWrapper from './components/FirstPage/PageWrapper/PageWrapper';
import {Route, Routes, HashRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './components/FirstPage/Header/Header';
import PageWrapper from './components/Second page/CollectionPage/PageWrapper/PageWrapper';
function App() {
  return (
    <HashRouter basename="/moviewebsite">
      <Header/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<FirstPageWrapper/>}/>
        <Route path='/collection' element={<PageWrapper />}/>
        <Route path='/activation' element={<h1>Activation page</h1>}/>
      </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```